# Call single eventlistener by one of two events?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying for a search functionality which should call a method on bean by either click event or by blur event, which ever is called first. I need both events because whenever user type something it should show results and if user has copied and paste into search box then also it should work. Since in second case there is no key event that's why I need blur event. I tried by putting separators between them like :

```
<f:ajax event="keyup blur" listener="#{mybean.search}" render="something">
```

also like

```
<f:ajax event="keyup,blur" listener="#{mybean.search}" render="something">
```

It didnt work

So now I am using my code as

```
<p:inputText value="#{mybean.search}" >
            <f:ajax listener="#{mybean.searchByIdListener}" event="keyup" render="datatable"/>
            <f:ajax listener="#{mybean.searchByIdListener}" event="blur" render="datatable"/>
</p:inputText>
```

But this code calls event listener two times. It would be good if event listener be called only one time by any of these two event which occur first.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about primefaces but in richfaces you can make use of ajax support and call the multiple events.
Else can you use `focus` event?

Comment: I in primefaces it has a tag as p:ajax which is similar to j:ajax . I have used that tag also. But same result. And focus event will not work for me bcoz I want to call eventlistener when user is entering something in search text box.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use something like this:

```
<p:inputText onchange="" />
```

From user guide:

```
Client side callback to execute when input element loses
focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus.
```

Comment: Thanx for reply. Actually for search method I need to show results as user enters any text on event keyup. And If user copy file and paste it into textbox through mouse then keyup event will not be fired at that time when user will remove focus then I want to call blur event. Since I have requirement of two events on single input method which is calling same method I cant use onchange attr. :(

Comment: if you still want use both events, add variable, which will show if first event was executed.

Comment: I think this is not a good idea becoz suppose keyup event was executed then I have also to check delete and backspace button. Suppose user has entered something then he delete that, after that he copies by mouse and paste it. In this case now it will not b executed bcoz it has already been executed by keyup. So I think its nt a good solution.